# Office-js, How to loop on the Styles of an Excel workbook

Tags: foreach, office-js

I would like to know how you can create a loop on Styles with Office-js

With VBA it's easy with the instruction For Each (For Each myStyle In Styles)

If it's possible, can you post some examples here or some links with documentation related.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Styles API feature is in our backlog. Not in the very short term; but should happen in 2/3rd Qtr.